# History API breaking when leaving page with History.JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I have the same problem with History.Js breaking whenever I return to the page that uses History API.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit http://ajax-pagination-html5.heroku.com/
2. Search for "tron"
3. Click on any result
4. Click back (only ajax is returned!)

Comment: Works in Firefox (11.0) but not in Chrome (18).

Comment: You spelt breaking wrong